# Find the maximum combination of values in a Cell structure?

Tags: matlab, cell, max, combinations

If I have the following cell :

```
a = cell(5,1);
a{1} = [1 3 1 0];
a{2} = [3 1 3 3];
a{3} = [3 2 3 2];
a{4} = [3 3 3 2];
a{5} = [3 2 3 3];
```

Typing `max(cell2mat(a))` gives `ans = 3 3 3 3`

But this doesn't make sense, as `3 3 3 3` doesn't even exist in that cell structure !! What is going on ? and how I can find the maximum combination that cell structure ?

*note*: I refer to maximum combination as in either `3 3 3 2` or `3 2 3 3` -- as both have the value `3` (the maximum) in 3/4 columns of `a{4}` and `a{5}`.

Comment: What do you want to do here? What is your expected output?

Comment: @wakjah I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want the following:

```
[~, maxInd] = max(sum(cell2mat(a), 2));
a{maxInd}

ans =

 3     3     3     2
```

If you want **all** the rows that have the same total value as the row with the maximum value then you can do:

```
% Take the sum along the rows of a
summedMat = sum(cell2mat(a), 2); 
% Find the value from the summed rows that is the highest
maxVal = max(summedMat);         
% Find any other rows that also have this total
maxInd = summedMat == maxVal;
% Get them rows!
a{maxInd}

ans =

 3     3     3     2


ans =

 3     2     3     3
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how the code is working ?? Would love to learn the method.

Answer (score 0):

max(A) gives returns the maximum value in each column of A.

So, if

```
A = cell2mat(a)
A =

   1   3   1   0
   3   1   3   3
   3   2   3   2
   3   3   3   2
```

`max(A)` is a vector containing the largest element in each column of A.

Comment: Thanks for explaining my error, didn't know that `max()` does that instead.